# How can I rearrange a set of values into new pattern on python and print results

Tags: python, arrays, list, loops, shuffle

so I will do my best to explain what I'm looking for,
at the moment I have a 100 item list that I want to repetitively shuffle using a set pattern to first check if the pattern will eventually bring me back to where I began
and 2 to print the result of each loop to a text file.

so using a 3 item list as my example
[a,b,c]
and the shuffle pattern [3 1 2]
where the 3rd item becomes the first.
the first item becomes the second
and the second item becomes the 3rd
on a loop would generate the following patterns

[a,b,c]

[3,1,2]

[c,a,b]

[b,c,a]

[a,b,c]

but I have a list at the moment of 100 items that I need to find every single arrangement for a few different patterns I would like to test out.

does anyone know of a way to do this in python please.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can define `function` and call this `function` multi times like below:

```
>>> def func(lst, ptr):
...    return [lst[idx-1] for idx in ptr]
 
>>> lst = ['a','b','c']
>>> ptr = [3,1,2]
>>> for _ in range(5):
...    lst = func(lst, ptr)
...    print(lst)

['c', 'a', 'b']
['b', 'c', 'a']
['a', 'b', 'c']
['c', 'a', 'b']
['b', 'c', 'a']
```

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for, Thankyou

Comment: @7090263 welcome :) ,  please read [this](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work)

Answer (score 0):

You could use numpy [advanced integer indexing](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/arrays.indexing.html#advanced-indexing) if your list contains a numeric type:

```py
import numpy as np

original_list=[1,2,3]
numpy_array = np.array(original_list)

pattern = [2,1,0]

print(numpy_array[pattern])
>>> array([3, 2, 1])
```

Answer (score 0):

```
def rearrange(pattern : list,L:list):
    new_list = []
    for i in pattern :
        new_list.append(L[i-1])
    return new_list

print(rearrange([3,1,2],['a','b','c']))
```

**output :**

```
['c', 'a', 'b']
```

Answer (score 0):

Itertools could be what you need.

```
import itertools

p = itertools.permutations(['a','b','c', 'd'])

list(p)
```

Output:
[('a', 'b', 'c', 'd'),
('a', 'b', 'd', 'c'),
('a', 'c', 'b', 'd'),
('a', 'c', 'd', 'b'),
('a', 'd', 'b', 'c'),
('a', 'd', 'c', 'b'),
('b', 'a', 'c', 'd'),
('b', 'a', 'd', 'c'),
('b', 'c', 'a', 'd'),
('b', 'c', 'd', 'a'),
('b', 'd', 'a', 'c'),
('b', 'd', 'c', 'a'),
('c', 'a', 'b', 'd'),
('c', 'a', 'd', 'b'),
('c', 'b', 'a', 'd'),
('c', 'b', 'd', 'a'),
('c', 'd', 'a', 'b'),
('c', 'd', 'b', 'a'),
('d', 'a', 'b', 'c'),
('d', 'a', 'c', 'b'),
('d', 'b', 'a', 'c'),
('d', 'b', 'c', 'a'),
('d', 'c', 'a', 'b'),
('d', 'c', 'b', 'a')]
​

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: not quite what I was looking for but thankyou for the advice on using permutations